# Shell scripting download and upload backed up files 

Tags: security, shell, shell-script, authentication

I have [gDisk](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gdisk/), I don't know if you have ever used it, it allows you to turn your GMail to a hard disk and host any file on it, I have many GMails that I don't use and I can create many others. To use gDisk all you have to do is enter your email and pass and if you checked auto login which will save your details, give it a try if you want just to see how it works.

Here's my question:

I would like to back up the files daily (which is easy) but here's the thing, I would like to download the back up to gdesk and upload them using a shell script when needed, I would like the process to be secure so that hackers will have hard time hacking the system, I know that gmail servers are secure, but I'm concerned about my server's requests :D

I don't want to leave my backup on my server and my connection is slow so downloading and uploading may take sometime and an automated way is a cool thing, and downloading and uploading directly from my vps to gdisk and vise versa would be so fast and google servers are secure :D

Do you think it could be done?

Comment: So what *exactly* is it you are asking for? Automated uploads to gDisk?

Comment: @grawity automated download, and not automated upload, a shell script that i have to manually run to upload backups, but automated downloads

Comment: ....waitamoment, "download *from* gdisk" or "download *to* gdisk"?

Comment: @grawity download from vps to gdisk...upload from gdisk to vps

Comment: Normally the terms are used like "upload to gdisk" (up to some remote place) and "download from gdisk"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of gDisk you could try [gmailfs](http://sr71.net/projects/gmailfs/), which you can run on your VPS. Write a cron job to simply `mv` any newly-uploaded backups to gmailfs.

Comment: THANK YOU, didn't know about gmailfs lol!!! who needs gdisk now? :D

Comment: read this http://bit.ly/ymTez it says that it does not work with the new gmail, what u think?

Comment: @elie: It also says, in big letters, "Dave Hansen has converted the code to use IMAP instead of the Gmail UI, please look at Dave's [IMAP Gmailfs](http://sr71.net/projects/gmailfs/) page for details." My answer also links to the exact same IMAP Gmailfs page.

Comment: So your goal here is to run software that violates Gmail's ToS, and you want to trust the backup of your software to this scheme rather than spending some money to back it up to a legitimate cloud storage service?  How ridiculous.

Comment: @gview well what is the difference between putting your script on google docs and on gmail? Does google really cares??? it's a zip file, not being shared by anyone so technically even if it's a trojan horse, it won't harm anyone so why am i violating Tos? google has more than 1 million servers, putting 3mb script won't harm the servers i suppose

Comment: @elieobeid:  Gmail is a mail system.  They make their money on providing free service by showing ads.  They don't want people turning it into a filesystem, and their terms of service spell this out.  The fact that like a needle in the haystack, people can violate the tos and get away with misusing the system for some period of time is not really the point.  The point is that at any time they may determine that you are doing this, and without warning, disable your account, and you will not have access to your backup data.